# VBA Excel to Word Document: How to Find and Replace ALL

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, find, office-automation

I'm using VBA to search for a given word (Ex, Cell A1) in a Word document, then replace that word in the Word doc with a value that corresponds to the cell beside it (cell B1).

Most instances of the words are only found once in the document, but I have some that repeat throughout. For these repeated ones, only the first instance is replaced and the rest aren't. I tried to find some solutions to this, but I've really only come across Excel-specific ones.

```
    Sub ReplaceAnnual()
'
'
'Declare Variables as Objects
    Dim oCell  As Integer
    Dim from_text As String, to_text As String
    Dim WA As Object
    Dim ws As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Dim IntialName As String
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant

'Open workbook and setting to the wb object for further use
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Pathway\Point_Estimates.xlsx")

'Set up Excel Application: sets currently open file as object
    Set ws = Workbooks("Point_Estimates")

'Set up Word Application
    Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     WA.Visible = True

'Opens Pre-Saved Document & activates it to use
    WA.Documents.Open "C:\Pathway\Filename.dotm"
    WA.Activate

  'Tells which cells to find and replace elements
    For oCell = 2 To 75
        from_text = Sheets("Values").Range("A" & oCell).Value
        to_text = Sheets("Values").Range("B" & oCell).Value
        
       'Specifies which application to work inside
        With WA.ActiveDocument
            Set myRange = .Content
            With myRange.Find
                .Execute FindText:=from_text, ReplaceWith:=to_text, Replace:=1
            End With
        End With
    Next oCell
    
    
'Activate Excel Worksheet
    ws.Activate
    
    'Declare where to find numbers for naming file (e.g. 2020)
    InitialName = "Point_Estimates_" & Range("B2")
    
        'Prompt dialog box and save
        fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
            fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")


        If fileSaveName <> False Then
        MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
        End If

'
'
End Sub
```

It ends with a prompt to save the Excel file with a specified name.
Any tips or help on tweaking this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify (in case it is unclear how I wrote it): the code pulls a word given in an Excel document to search for in a specified Word document. Then it replaces that found word with a value that's also found in the Excel document.

Comment: If you had used the [online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdreplace) you would have realised that you have used the wrong value for the `Replace` parameter.